# Is it possible to combine multiple (>2) matrices based on row AND column names and a weighting factor?

Tags: r, matrix, reshape2

I have a list that contains hundreds of matrices, each with column names and row names. Each matrix is slightly different from one another - some contain certain column and row names that others will not have. I also have a vector of weights (between 0 and 1) to apply to each of the matrices through simple multiplication.

I am trying to combine them all into one large matrix that contains ALL the row names and ALL the column names. I found a post on SO ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26042738/r-add-matrices-based-on-row-and-column-names)) that helped when I was testing the code with only 10 matrices in the list. In the post, the user was only combining two matrices. However, since I was combining multiple, I had to wrap my function into nested for loops. However, as I am now running the code live, it doesn't work anymore as the overall matrix is too large (1200+ rows by 2300+ columns).

Happy to explain further if it doesn't make sense from the other post.

It's difficult to put in sample code for such large datasets, but I'll try to make an example below.

```
markov_chains is a list with many matrices
markov_chains[[1]] = 
  a b c d ...
v 1 1 1 0 
w 1 1 0 1 
x 1 0 1 1 
y 0 1 1 1 
...

markov_chains[[2]] = 
  d e aa a ...
y 1 1 1  0 
w 1 1 0  1 
v 1 0 1  1 
z 0 1 1  1 
...
```

but imagine that each of these columns had 1000 rows and 1000 columns. Each matrix also has a weighting function, for example 0.5 for [[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26042738/r-add-matrices-based-on-row-and-column-names)], 0.22 for [[2]], etc.

In the end, I'm trying to combine them into some sort of master matrix like below:

```
markov_master = 
    a   b    c    d    e    ...    aa    ...    zzz
z  0.7 0.1  0.2  1.2  0.9   ...   0.1    ...     4
y   1  1.5  1.2  0.4  0.1   ...   6.5    ...     7
x  1.1 0.5  2.3  7.0  0.7   ...   2.9    ...     2
w  0.9 1.5  5.8  4.1  0.2   ...   7.9    ...    1.1
...
```

Comment: Please include minimal sample data; it's much easier for others to help if you provide actual data instead of describing how the data looks.

Comment: Hi Maurits, I've added some example data. Does this help?